# How to start activity from FREFunction?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air-native-extension

I'm trying to start and activity from a FREFunction to use facebooks's SSO on my flex application.

I did in my FREFunction:

```
    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(context.getActivity(), FacebookSSO.class);
         context.getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
         return null;
    }
```

I get with logcat:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1322): Starting activity: 
Intent{ cmp=air.testapp/com.test.android.ane.activity.FacebookSSO } from pid...
```

But my log calls in the onCreate method of are FacebookSSO.java are not displayed:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //setContentView(R.layout.main);
     Log.d("FacebookSSO", "onCreate BEGIN.");
     Log.d("FacebookSSO", "onCreate END.");
 }
```

I tried creating myIntent in different ways, like using setClass. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you figured this out by any chance? I am trying to do the exact same thing. Though, I am running through Flash Builder, so I actually don't know how to get any Logcat information as it seems to connect to a Flash debugger only.

Comment: Nope. Trying to do it from scratch cause this project does the same thing and it worked for me: http://blog.immanuelnoel.com/2011/12/07/new-actionscript-native-extension-speech-recognition/

Comment: Damn. Yes I noticed that project too. I tried their method of making a SpeechHandler Activity, but I think they did that as some kind of work around for starting the true speech activity with a return result.

Sadly I couldn't get the SpeechHandler to spawn my Activity either. Let me know if you get it working.

Comment: It's working. Like I said I did it from scratch, after importing the Speech project on my own and displaying its string result in my application label...
I really have no clue what might have been. But one of the things I neglected was registering the activity on my Flex's manifest and NOT only on the original android manifest.

Comment: Sadly I had done both, and it still never worked.

Answer (score 1):

Did you solve this problem?

Have you tried adding the class into the manifest additions in your application descriptor?

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <application>
                <activity android:name="com.test.android.ane.activity.FacebookSSO"></activity>
            </application>
        </manifest>
    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Intent constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) you are using is expecting a Context as its parameter (remember that [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) *is a* Context also.)

Because the constructor is expecting a Context and you are starting with a context there should be no need to call `getActivity()`. Also `startActivity()` is a method of [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29), So you shouldn't need the `getActivity()` in the second line either. However I don't know if that would result in the error you are seeing.

Try your code this way:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, FacebookSSO.class);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But that won't work cause context is of type FREContext which means undefined constructor error. Is any sort of cast possible?

Comment: Ahh, sorry I got nothing then. Am not familiar with the Air platform, didn't realize it had its own version of Context.